# How to retreive image captions from cloudinary and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metadata, cloudinary

I'm trying to add a caption below my cloudinary image.  On the cloudinary website, I've added my caption under the "edit metadata" field, but I can't figure out how to retrieve it.

My controller:

```
require 'cloudinary'
results = Cloudinary::Api.resources(:type => :upload)
resources = results["resources"]
@ids = resources.map {|res| res["public_id"]}
```

My view:

```
<% @ids.each do |id| %>
  <%= cl_image_tag (id) %>
  **insert caption here**
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the image metadata you've inserted, you'll have to set `context` to `true` when running the `resources` method, like this:

`results = Cloudinary::Api.resources(:type => :upload, :context => true)`

The above request will also return key-value pairs as in the metadata you've inserted, like this:

`"context"=>{"custom"=>{"caption"=>"flowers"}}`

Comment: Any tips on how to efficiently extract the caption when not all photos in the list have captions?